# Loading a file through ClassLoader not working in java?

Tags: java

**SampleClass.java** and **keywords.properties** are present in this location in my system :
 **/home/user/Projects/SampleProject/src/main/java/com/package/subPackage/** 
SampleClass.java have both static and non-static functions.
In static function ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(FILE_PATH)
In non-static function this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE_PATH)

But It returns null in InputStream.I tried every possible combination for FILE_PATH like this :

/home/user/Projects/SampleProject/src/main/java/com/package/subPackage/prefix.properties
 src/main/java/com/package/subPackage/prefix.properties
com/package/subPackage/prefix.properties
prefix.properties

I followed these links
[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/loading-java-properties-files/

Nothing worked for me . Please suggest me where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

besides that resources should be put in the `resources` folder and not in main source, try `/com/package/subPackage/prefix.properties`

Comment: I tried you suggestion FILE_PATH = "/com/package/subPackage/prefix.properties"  but It didn't work .But resource folder thing worked for me. In my project there is already resources folder.I created a config folder and added prefix.properties (new location : /home/user/Projects/SampleProject/src/resources/config/prefix.properties).Updated FILE_PATH = "config/prefix.properties" and it worked .Thanks

Comment: do you have a maven project ? I assumed by the path you gave.... then the resource files should be in `src/main/resources/`

Comment: Yeah It's Maven and you are right resources  in that folder path  "src/main/resources/"